# Difference between importing a .h file and inheriting a class

Tags: objective-c, xcode

What is the difference between importing a header file of a class and inheriting a class?

Person.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Person:NSObject
{float fromPerson;}
-(void)inPerson;
@end
```

case 1 - importing Person.h in Employee.h

```
#import "Person.h"

@interface Employee:NSObject
{float fromEmployee;}
-(void)inEmployee;
@end
```

case 2 - inheriting Person.h into Employee.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Person.h"

@interface Employee:Person
{float fromInheritedEmployee;}
-(void)inInheritedEmployee;
@end
```

Comment: What _specifically_ are you confused about?

Comment: I can declare an instance of Person in case 1 and 2. I can access the variable: fromPerson in both the cases. So what is the advantage of inheriting class Person?

Comment: If instead you declare an instance of Employee, you can access the inherited `fromPerson` in case 2, but not in case 1.

Comment: So i suppose it's relation or identity. Do I have some other thing? (i.e. Book has Pages, but a Page is not a Book) Or I am this other thing? (i.e. An Employee is a Person, but a Person does not have an Employee)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importing an header file is just copying of its content to current file, e.g. declarations, macros, enums etc.

inheriting a class means that the class that you now declared is a sub-class of the inherited class, e.g. Employee is a Person.

Comment: In that case, what can I do in inherited class that I cannot do in imported class, and vice versa?

Comment: The two terms are not related. @sidyll answer seems better to me (+1)

Comment: Thanks a lot sidyll and Binyamin!

Answer (score 3):

Importing  using a  preprocessor  directive  is a  job  for the  preprocessor,
obviously,  which  runs  before  the   actual  compiling.  That  directive  is
interpreted as "take the contents of  *Person.h* and place them here", so it's
like if you had copied and pasted the contents of *Person.h* in *Enployee.h*.

In practical terms, this makes the  compiler aware of the definitions included
in *Employee.h*. So,  if you use an  object of the `Employee`  class (which is
declared in *Employee.h*) it will know what to do with it.

This  has nothing  to do  with inheritance,  which is  a completely  different
process which  you should  take a  closer look  in your  favorite OOP  book or
document.

The file name is completely independent,  don't let that trick you. *Person.h*
could be called *Being.h* and include class definitions for higher beings, all
in the  same file, and then  importing it would place  it's definitions inside
the file  *Employee.h*, which would not  by any means affect  from which class
`Employee`inherits.

Answer (score 1):

### a primer on #include vs #import

importing (or including) a file is akin to injecting the contents of that file at the location of the #import statement.

#### Interesting details:

In Objective-C #import is smarter than the normal C #include in that if a file is already previously injected in an embedded #import chain, then it won't be injected again.  the normal C (preprocessor) #include is not smart enough to figure that out which is why you always see constructs like

```
   #ifndef __FOO_H
   #define __FOO_H

   .... header content here ...

   #endif /*__FOO_H */
```

In C headers to ensure singular inclusions, whereas you don't see such constructs in objective C.

That is all what `#import` is: a content injection mechanism.

So, taking your own example, let's say I wanted to create an instance of the Person class, I would have to #import its definition before I could do that. :

```
  /* main.m */

  #import "Person.h"

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

            Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];  
            //^^^^^^^^ this won't work without the #import statement
            [person release];
            return 0;
  }
```

note that nothing is being inherited, #import just injects all the pieces needed to use the `Person` class in our main.m

## a primer on inheritance

Inheritance is, as you probably already know, a mechanism to define a new class as an extension of another class.  Typically, the new class is a subclass of the parent class (think animal kingdom), but not always.

In your own example you define Employee as a sub-class of a Person.

### So how does inheritance relate to #import?

Well in order to use a class for *anything* you need to #import its definition so that the compiler knows what you are talking about when you say `Person`, and that includes (pun intended) creating a derived class.